# I want to show there exist more than one measure on $\sigma (\mathcal A_{0})$ in $\mathbb Q$ which agree with $\mu$ on $\mathcal A_{0}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal A$ denote the algebra $\mathcal A=\mathcal A(\mathcal S)$.(where $\mathcal S$ denote the collection of intervals of the form $(a,b]$ where $-\infty\le a \lt b \le \infty$)
 Let $\Omega=\mathbb Q$ denote the set of rational numbers in $\mathbb R$, and let $\mathcal A_{0}=\mathcal A \cap \mathbb Q$. Consider the measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal A_{0}$ by $\mu(A)=0$ or $\infty$ according to whether $A=\emptyset$ or $A\neq \emptyset$. Show that there exist more than one measure on $\sigma (\mathcal A_{0})$ in $\mathbb Q$ whith agree with $\mu$ on $\mathcal A_{0}$.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps :

1. Prove that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_0) = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$, the power set of $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. Let $\mu_1(A) = |A|$. Show that $\mu_1$ is an extension of $\mu$
3. Let $\mu_2(A) = 0$ or $+\infty$ according to whether $A = \emptyset$ or $A\neq \emptyset$. Show that $\mu_2$ is an extension of $\mu$
4. Show that $\mu_2 \neq \mu_1$